# One object is not moving

Tags: python, pygame

I am very new to pygame and python, and recently started creating the following for the school project but the problem is that, the object apple is not moving or dropping down, but everything else works fine! Please help me out! My complete code is as follows:

```
import sys, pygame, random
from menu_lib import *
from credit import credit

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super(Player, self).__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('catcher_left.png')
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320,240), self.image.get_size())
        self.rect.bottom = 452
        self.rect.left = 320

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 10
            self.image = pygame.image.load('catcher_left.png')
            pygame.display.flip()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 10
            self.image = pygame.image.load('catcher_right.png')
            pygame.display.flip()
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > 640:
            self.rect.right = 640
        #if self.rect.colliderect(Apple.rect):
            #print "Collided!"

class Apple(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('apple.png')
        self.rect=pygame.rect.Rect((32,37), self.image.get_size())
        self.rect.top=0
        self.rect.left=0

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.top, self.rect.left))

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.top==0:
            self.rect.top+=10
            self.rect.left=random.randint(10, 630)
        elif self.rect.top!=0 and self.rect.top>480:
            self.rect.top+=10
        elif self.rect.top>=480:
            self.rect.top=0

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
        background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (640, 480))
        apple_count=0
        sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(sprites)
        apple = Apple()

        while 1:
            clock.tick(30)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    screen.fill((0,0,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    Mainmenu()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    screen.fill((0,0,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    Mainmenu()

            sprites.update()
            apple.update()
            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            sprites.draw(screen)
            apple.draw(screen)
            score_txt='Score: '+str(apple_count)
            label = myfont.render(score_txt, 1, (255,0,0))
            screen.blit(label, (500, 10))
            pygame.display.flip()


def Mainmenu():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    menu = cMenu(50, 50, 20, 5, 'vertical', 300, screen,
           [('Start Game', 1, None),
            ('Credits',    2, None),
            ('Exit',       3, None)])

    menu.set_center(True, True)

    menu.set_alignment('center', 'center')

    state = 0
    prev_state = 1

    rect_list = []

    pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEMOTION)

    while 1:
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if prev_state != state:
         pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(EVENT_CHANGE_STATE, key = 0))
         prev_state = state

        e = pygame.event.wait()

        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or e.type == EVENT_CHANGE_STATE:
         if state == 0:
            rect_list, state = menu.update(e, state)
         elif state == 1:
             screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
             Game().main(screen)
         elif state == 2:
             credits()
         else:
            print 'Exit!'
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update(rect_list)

def credits():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    text = "Credits \n _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ \n\n\n Designer \n Creator \n\n Manikiran P"
    color = 0xa0a0a000
    credit(text,myfont,color)
    Mainmenu()
    while 1:
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                pygame.display.flip()
                Mainmenu()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                pygame.display.flip()
                Mainmenu()

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Evenure - (c) Manikiran")
    myfont = pygame.font.Font("captureit.ttf", 20)
    Mainmenu()
```

Comment: `Apple.update` only does anything if `self.rect.top` is exactly 0 or at least 480. Is that what you want? Perhaps you got a comparison flipped.

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to say! And i am very new to Pygame!

Comment: @user3699054 this is nothing to do with `pygame`; look at `Apple.update` and think about what path you take through the function if `self.rect.top == 10`.

Comment: Reread the `update` method in the `Apple` class, paying close attention to which way the `>` signs are pointing.

Comment: The same code worked when i took apple_x and apple_y without having apple as sprite, so why now?

Comment: My guess would be you screwed up the change, perhaps by mistyping something.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! I screwed up exactly in the if statement. Error: self.rect.top>480; Correction: self.rect.top<480;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have miss-typed in the elif statement:

```
elif self.rect.top!=0 and self.rect.top>480:
```

Correction:

```
elif self.rect.top!=0 and self.rect.top<480:
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and i cannot vote up because i don't have enough reputation!